# I want to emphasize on a particular adjective

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure, emphasis

Consider the following sentence please:

> We need to give young people more opportunity if we want them to grow
> into responsible adults.

I guess everyone who reads the text feels that giving opportunity is the main point, but I would like to put a strong emphasize on being young. Is it correct If I paraphrase like this?

> We need to give people more opportunity in their youth if we want them
> to grow into responsible adults.

I mean, I want the reader to understand that giving chance to **young people** is important in my view. I mean it is important that we give people opportunities when they are young rather than adult.

Comment: I doubt that it makes any difference whether you speak about young people or **in their youth**. You would need to rephrase your sentence along these lines: **It's young people who need to be given (whom we need to give) more opportunity.......

Comment: I don't see that you need to change anything. The first sentence is very clear that young people is whom we need to give more responsibility to.

Comment: Yes, the second sentence better emphasizes that young people need the opportunities, not adults.

Comment: :| Three comments, none of them agree with each other. Thanks people but I got more confused. :)

Answer (score 1):

As you mention "readers" I'll assume that this is written English.

It is possible to rephrase, though your rephrasing doesn't seem to give much emphasis to "young", instead it rather makes "in their youth" seem to be an afterthought.

You can add emphasis with font changes:

> We need to give *young* people ...

The reader will imagine that this is spoken with contrastive stress.  Using **young** people is even stronger stress, and probably too much (Use bold to make words stand out to readers before they've read the text, not as they are reading the text)

Comment: Thanks it is a good suggestion. But I doubt that font is a part of language!